# ffmpegのlibx264について質問です。

Tags: ffmpeg

```sh
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -threads 2 -codec:v libx264 -s:v 1280x720 -aspect:v 16:9 -b:v 256k -map 0 -f segment -segment_format mpegts -segment_time 10 -segment_list stream.m3u8 streamfiles/stream%03d.ts
```

ffmpeg のこのコマンドでエンコードを行うと、

> Unknown encoder 'libx264'

という表示がでて libx264 がないという表示がでます。

私は iOS でストリーム再生がしたくて動画を mp4 に h.264 でエンコードしたいのですが、これは libx264 が元からなくてできないんでしょうか？

`ffmpeg -formats` で見たところ、 libx264 はなくて h264 がありました。しかし、映像/音声コーデックの種類は D と E だけで V がありませんでしたし、 h264 でやった場合も同じ `Unknown encoder` とでます。

この場合 V がないとエンコードができないんでしょうか？
もし V が必要なのであれば追加方法を教えてください。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `ffmpeg -h 2>&1 | grep 'enable-libx264'` を実行してみて下さい。何も表示されない場合は、ffmpeg に libx264 がリンクされていません。

Comment: コーデックの一覧は`-codecs`オプションで得られます。そこに無ければインストールされていないのかもしれませんね。インストール方法はOSなどによると思います。

Comment: x264はインストールできていると思うので、ffmpegにリンクされていないのかもしれないです