# ffmpegでvp9の動画をH.264にエンコードしたい。

Tags: python, python3, ffmpeg, mp4

ffmpeg-pythonでvp9の動画をH.264にエンコードしたいのですが上手く行きません。vp9の動画ファイルとaacの音声ファイルを結合させるプログラムを書いたのですが、`vcodec`の値をlibx264かh264に変更すれば上手くできると思ったのですが途中に下記のエラーが出ます。

**エラー**

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.3-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
      Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (vp9 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
      Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    [libx264 @ 0x73895c0] using SAR=1/1
    [libx264 @ 0x73895c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
    [libx264 @ 0x73895c0] profile High, level 5.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
    [libx264 @ 0x73895c0] 264 - core 160 r3000 33f9e14 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2020 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
    Output #0, mp4, to 'video/joined/scarlxrd - NEW LEVEL.mp4':
      Metadata:
        encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
        Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libx264
        Side data:
          cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
        Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 160 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Traceback (most recent call last):    0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
      File "test.py", line 129, in <module>
        Downloader.join_audio_video()
      File "test.py", line 121, in join_audio_video
        ffmpeg.run(stream)
      File "/home/vagrant/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ffmpeg/_run.py", line 325, in run
        raise Error('ffmpeg', out, err)
    ffmpeg._run.Error: ffmpeg error (see stderr output for detail)
```

途中まではしっかり動作しているような気がします。
**コード**

```
            instream_v = ffmpeg.input(videopath)
            instream_a = ffmpeg.input(title_aac)
            stream = ffmpeg.output(instream_v, instream_a, title_join, vcodec="h264", acodec="copy") #ここのvscodecでエラー
            ffmpeg.run(stream)
```

下記のリンク先で似たような質問があったので`ffmpeg -formats`と`ffmpeg -codecs`を実行しましたがいずれにもh264、H.264の記述がありました。

**ffmpeg -h 2>&1 | grep 'enable-libx264'実行結果**

```
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
```

どなたか詳しい方教えて頂けると助かります。
よろしくお願いします。

追記

```
ffmpeg.run(capture_stdout=True, capture_stderr=True)
```

このコードを記述することでstderrの中身が確認可能ということで実行しましたが、下記のエラーが出力されました。

```
TypeError: run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'stream_spec'
```

`ffmpeg.run(stream_spec, capture_stdout=True, capture_stderr=True)`これで実行してみたのですが、同じエラーが出力されます。

[ffmpegのlibx264について質問です。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/17180/ffmpeg%E3%81%AElibx264%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99)

Comment: 出力はそれで全てですか？状況を把握するのに必要な肝心な部分が抜けている気がします……

Comment: Ffmpeg 自体は単体でも動作するツールです。過去の質問もそうですが、質問の範囲を絞り込む意味でも、本当にPythonラッパーが必要なのかを検討してください。 / できれば Ffmpeg のバージョン情報も含めたほうがよいと思います。

Comment: すいません。最初の部分をコピー出来ていませんでした。必要な部分と思われるもの記述しました。そこにバージョンも記載されています。

Comment: Pythonしか書けないので、ラッパーを使用しています。個人的にはPythonを勉強したくて使用しています。

Comment: ラッパーを使おうと結局は「Python + Ffmpeg」の知識が必要となります。Ffmpeg 単体で使えば Ffmpeg 自体の使い方で事足ります。 / 私自身は Python に詳しくないのでコメントに控えますが、エラーの最後に出ている通り、stderr の出力内容も確認しないと詳しい状況が分からないと思います。

Comment: Pyhonの他のモジュールと一緒に使用したくてラッパーを使用しています。ラッパー使用しない場合はやはりPythonの処理が終了してから、スクリプトを起動させて動作させる必要がありますね。

Comment: もしかして動画をストリームするスペックがないという事でしょうか？Vagrantの仮装環境内で実行しています。

Comment: （今の最下部のエラーは）`ffmpeg.run(stream)`で指定しているstreamが抜けているということでは。私からもまずはpythonを通さずに直接CLIインタフェースを利用することおおすすめします。（ffmpegの引数は確かに複雑ですがPythonを挟んだところでさらに複雑になっているだけです）

Comment: 上手く動作しました。原因はメモリ不足でメモリを当てたら動作しました。お騒がせしました。

Comment: [前回の投稿](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/67834) も同じですが、解決策は質問に追記するのではなく [個別の回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) として投稿してください。 / 参考: メタでの関連する討議 - https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3339

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vagrant の仮装環境内で実行していましたが、メモリ不足によるものでした。
メモリの割り当て量を 1GB → 4GB に増量することで正常に動作しました。